# Проблема с переадресацией asp.core

Tags: c#, html, asp

я делаю сайт, по обучающему видео, на сайте есть разделы автомобили с двс и электрокары, если я нажимаю на кнопку fuel я вижу авто с двс, дальше нажимаю на electro и в адресную строку добавляются параметры, то есть не заменяются, а добавляются "https://localhost:44319/Cars/ShowCars/Cars/ShowCars/electro", если в адресной строке написать "https://localhost:44319/Cars/ShowCars/electro", то всё работает.

```
[Route("Cars/ShowCars")]
[Route("Cars/ShowCars/{category}")]
public IActionResult ShowCars(string category)
{
    string _category = category;
    IEnumerable<Car> cars = null;
    string currCategory = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
    {
        cars = _allCars.GetAllCars.OrderBy(i => i.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        if (string.Equals("electro", category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            cars = _allCars.GetAllCars.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryName.Equals("Электромобили")).OrderBy(i => i.Id);
            currCategory = "Электромобили";
        }
        else if (string.Equals("fuel", category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            cars = _allCars.GetAllCars.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryName.Equals("Классический автомобили")).OrderBy(i => i.Id);
            currCategory = "Классический автомобили";
        }
        

    }

    var carobj = new CarsListViewModel
    {
        GetAllCars = cars,
        CurrentCategory = currCategory
    };
    
    return View(carobj);
}
```

Вот кнопки в хедере

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">shop of car</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Cars/ShowCars">All Cars</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Cars/ShowCars/electro">Electro Cars</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Cars/ShowCars/fuel">Fuel Cars</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Вот класс startUp

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_conString.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        
        services.AddTransient<ICars, CarRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ICarsCategory, CategoryRepository>();
        
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped(sp => ShopCart.GetCart(sp));

        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(name: "categoryFilter", template: "Cars/{action}/{category?}", defaults: new { Controller = "Cars", action = "ShowCars" });

        });

        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
            AppDbContext context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
            DbObjects.init(context);

        }
    }
```

Ещё раз говорю, если открыть сайт, то по всем кнопкам переходит без проблем, что на все авто, на электро и на двс, но если один раз нажал, что-то, то на другую страницу уже не попадёшь, ибо url будет не меняться, а добавляться к существующему.

Comment: `href="/Cars/ShowCars"` слеш в начеле путей добавьте, без слеша это ссылка относительно текущей страницы, со слешем - относительно web root.

Comment: спасибо, как всегда выручаешь!